# What is a proper signature of Executor.execute(​????) in Sangria middleware to log slow GraphQL queries?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I am trying to integrate Sangria middleware to log slow GraphQL queries in my application but getting the following compilation

Error:

> type mismatch;
>   found   : sangria.schema.Schema[models.UserRepo,Unit]
>   required: sangria.schema.Schema[Any,Unit]
>   Note:models.UserRepo <:Any,but class Schema is invariant in type
>   Ctx.
>   You may wish to define Ctx as +Ctx instead. (SLS 4.5)
>   Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

Code snippet:

```
val Query = ObjectType("Query", List[Field[UserRepo, Unit]]
(Field("store", StoreType, resolve = _ ⇒ ()) ))

val schema = Schema(Query, Some(MutationType))

val logResult = Executor.execute(SchemaDefinition.schema,
  query.asInstanceOf[Document], middleware = SlowLog(newlogger,
  threshold = 10 seconds) :: Nil)
```

Here is the reference link: https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria-slowlog

Kindly help me to know what is a proper signature of `Executor.execute(​​​????)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue is that you've defined the schema in terms of `UserRepo`, but you haven't provided it at the execution time. I guess adding a `userContext` argument should fix the issue:

```
Executor.execute(SchemaDefinition.schema, query,
  userContext = new UserRepo,
  middleware = SlowLog(newlogger, threshold = 10 seconds) :: Nil)
```

I also made this test to check the types (these types are similar to your scenario), but it compiles just fine:

```
val schema: Schema[Repo, Unit] = ???
val md: Middleware[Any] = ???

Executor.execute(schema, query, new Repo, middleware = md :: Nil)
```

If it still does not compile, I would suggest you to provide complete self-contains example that reproduces the issue. (for instance, in your example you don't show the type of `MutationType`)

Comment: Now I am using this:
Executor.execute(SchemaDefinition.schema, query.asInstanceOf[Document], UserRepo.this,
      middleware = SlowLog(logger2, threshold = 10 seconds) :: Nil)

Comment: And when I run a query:
{
  store {
    makes(year: "1999") {
      value
    }
  }
}
, On my terminal getting this prblem:
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to sangria.ast.Document,

My query format is : 
val query = "g.V().has('BaseVehicle','YearID','" + year + "').out('make').dedup()"

Comment: And response  is :
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "path": [
        "store",
        "makes"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
, Please suggest me how to cast a String to Document or any other solution to fix this, 

Thanks !!

Comment: Or What is the format of query which is to pass in Executer.execute(,query,..)

Comment: I would suggest you to check out the [getting started tutorial](http://sangria-graphql.org/getting-started/) and documentation about [query parsing](http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#query-parser-and-renderer)